# SetWindowPos implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-monitors

I need open two instances of internet browser and each instance open in different monitor (have two) from console app. I found SetWindowPos method and can't find way to use it. In my case it doesn't do anything...

Please help me way to right using of this method...

Here is the code what I'm using for:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

    public static void Launch()
    {
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "microsoft.com";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;


        process.Start();

        Rectangle monitor = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
        SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, monitor.Left, monitor.Top, monitor.Width - 200, monitor.Height, 0);
    }
```

Thanks David

Comment: This is hard to get reliable, IE is a "single instance" app.  Even if it is the first instance you start, you "have to wait a while" before the handle is valid.  Process.WaitForInputIdle() isn't enough.

Comment: If you need that much control over the browser, perhaps you'd be better off hosting it explicitly. Then you can place it anywhere you like. Alternatively, you can create an `InternetExplorer` object and set its `Top`, `Left`, etc. properties.

Answer (score 0):

That window handle you're passing to the method is empty as the process has not had time to open its main window.

Try adding a reasonable timeout before calling SetWindowPos, a second or two should be enough:

```
process.Start();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
process.WaitForInputIdle(); // just in case

SetWindowPos(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would work, for example, with notepad.exe. With iexplore.exe is not working because `process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero`, and `process.HasExited == true`. You need to find the right way to find a window handle.